# nginx as elasticsearch loadbalancer has low performance

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, load-balancing

I am trying to configure an nginx as Load Balancer in front of an Elastic Search Cluster (version 1.3.7).

I am testing from 3 benchmark servers to 3 elasticsearch nodes in a cluster.
Using nginx as LoadBalancer I have a decrease in performance about 50%.

I am able to handle 28K requests in 300 secs without the nginx but with it, only 13k in 300 secs .
The servers are VM, so should not be a Network issue, at least, a physical one. 
Nginx server do not has High cpu load or any limit in their resources.

Config is pretty simple:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}
```

and the specific for ES:

```
server {
    listen       9100;
    server_name elasticsearch.site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}

upstream elasticsearch {
    server elasticsearch1:9200;
    server elasticsearch2:9200;
    server elasticsearch3:9200;
    keepalive 15;
}
```

I wish to know if there is any way to understand why nginx cannot deliver more requests per second, or if there is any way to debug this cases.
Understand timeouts, keep alive connection or any other resource handled by nginx would be great.

Comment: Try haproxy maybe? If you particularly want some sort of load balancing anyway.

Comment: I won't be surprised if buffering is the reason for the slowness your application encounter. Two configuration option to consider tuning: [proxy_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering) and [proxy_request_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering).